# vector.erase and std::remove on custom vector

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I have a vector of int pairs. Assuming Itr as my iterator for this vector.
I want to iterate over the vector and make a decision whether or not to remove the element from the vector. If the element of the vector is `9001,3` then i want to remove all the elements from the vector whose `itr->first` is 9001(irrespective or what `itr->second` is).

**Questions:**

1. How do i remove this vector of int pairs. The following wouldn't work:
   `vec.erase(std::remove(vec.begin(), vec.end(), Itr->first=9001), vec.end());`
2. Instead of giving a range as vec.begin() to vec.end() is it possible for me to give 
   vec.begin as  `(current element being pointer by vector) - 10` and
   ve.end as `(current element being pointed by vector)+10` ?

Example:`vec.erase(std::remove(Itr-10, Itr+10, Itr->first=9001), vec.end());`

It might quiet be possible that Itr+10 ot Itr-10 will result in a segmentation fault if the vector size itself is less than 10. So how to deal with this situation?

```
    vector<pair<int,int> > vec;

    vec.push_back(pair<int,int>(9001,1));
    vec.push_back(pair<int,int>(9001,2));
    vec.push_back(pair<int,int>(9001,3));
    vec.push_back(pair<int,int>(9001,4));
    vec.push_back(pair<int,int>(9002,1));
    vec.push_back(pair<int,int>(9002,2));
    vec.push_back(pair<int,int>(9002,3));
    vec.push_back(pair<int,int>(9002,4));
    vec.push_back(pair<int,int>(9002,5));


    vector<pair<int,int> >::iterator Itr;
    for(Itr=vec.begin();Itr!=vec.end();++Itr)
            cout<<vecItr->first<<" "<<vecItr->second;

//  vec.erase(std::remove(Itr-10, Itr+10, Itr->first=9001), vec.end()); //This doest work

    for(Itr=vec.begin();Itr!=vec.end();++Itr)
            cout<<Itr->first<<" "<<Itr->second;
```

Comment: How about using [`std::remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) with an appropriate lambda instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do i remove this vector of int pairs. The following wouldn't work:

Use lambda or custom comparator with `remove_if` algorithm:

```
vec.erase(std::remove_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 
                         [](auto& elem){ return elem.first == 9001;} ),
          vec.end());
```

Using custom comparator:

```
struct elem_equals
{
    typedef std::pair<int,int> elem_t
    const int value;

    elem_equals(int v) : value(v) {}

    bool operator()(elem_t& elem) 
    {
        return elem.first == value;
    }
};

//...

vec.erase(std::remove_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 
                         elem_equals(9001) ),
          vec.end());
```

> Instead of giving a range as vec.begin() to vec.end() is it possible for me to give vec.begin as `(current element being pointer by vector) - 10` and `ve.end as (current element being pointed by vector)+10` ?

Yes. Vector iterator support pointer arithmetics, so it is easy.

> It might quiet be possible that Itr+10 ot Itr-10 will result in a segmentation fault if the vector size itself is less than 10. So how to deal with this situation?

Clamp your range if there is not enough elements before or after iterator:

```
//iter is an iterator to vector
//vec is instance of std::vector
//replace auto with std::vector<std::pair<int,int> >::iterator for non C++11 compilers
auto begin = iter - std::min(10, iter - vec.begin());
auto end = iter + std::min(10, vec.end() - iter);
```

Comment: The lambda doesn't receive an iterator, but an actual element.  Using auto  in lambda parameters is c++14.

Comment: @stefaanv thanks, fixed. As for C++14, there is no requirement to not use it. But I will change it anyway.

Comment: Unfortunately im not on C++11 or higher to use lambda. Any other option for me?

Comment: @anurag86 , sure, custom comparator. I will edit my answer and add example right now

Comment: I'm not saying that you shouldn't use C++14, I'm just pointing out to those trying your example.  It may be a bit confusing with 2 remarks in 1.